# Select only parent records when all children records meet conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I have two tables A and B where I only want the parent A's rows when all the children (in Table B) meet the criteria. If one row from B does not meet the criteria, then I don't need parent A's row.  I think I need to use exists here, but not show how.

Here are the data tables:

Table A

```
Primary Key Level
1   low
2   low
3   high 
4   high 
5   low
```

Table B

```
Primary Key Phase   Parent Primary Key
1   open    1
2   open    1
3   close   1
4   close   2
5   close   2
6   close   3
7   open    4
8   open    4
9   open    5
10  close   5
```

And the query I was trying:

```
select * 
from table_a, table_b
where table_a.level = 'low' and
      table_b.phase = 'close' and
      table_a.primary_key=table_b.parent_primary_key
```

but my query would also return rows where the table_a.primary_key = 5.

Basically the only rows I want returned is when table_A.primary_key = 2 beause the level is low, and both children rows have a phase equal to close.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try *exactly* like that, with the words `low` and `close` not enclosed in single-quotes, and still got results? That shouldn't even compile (you should get an "invalid identifier" error).

Comment: No, sorry I had quotes around low and close. I was having issues trying to post it exactly the way it was here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where a.level = 'low' and
      'close' = all (select phase
                  from table_b b
                  where b.parent_primary_key = a.primary_key
                 );
```

Comment: thank you for your help! this is a great alternative too

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where a.level = 'low' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b
                  where b.parent_primary_key = a.primary_key and
                        b.phase <> 'close'
                 );
```

The `not exists` is a double negative.  It checks that there are no children with a phase other than `'close'` -- which is basically equivalent to saying that all children are `'close'`.  (If `NULL` values are allowed, the logic is not exactly equivalent.)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! So could you help with explaining how the not exists works in this situation please?

Comment: I noticed that you have 'select a.*', is there a way to get the output to have all the data from both tables?