# Query that brings all the parents whose children meet a certain criteria

Tags: android, sqlite, select, where-clause

I need a query that brings all the parents whose children meet a certain criteria.

So far this is giving me something different than expected:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM piece_unit_table put WHERE (SELECT et.date_of_creation FROM expense_table et WHERE et.piece_unit_parent_id = put.piece_unit_id) = :dateOfExpenseCreation AND project_id = :projectId")
public abstract LiveData<List<PieceUnit>> getPieceUnitsWhereDateOfExpenseCreation(long dateOfExpenseCreation, int projectId);
```

A more readable version of the same code above:

```
SELECT * 
FROM piece_unit_table put 
WHERE (
   SELECT et.date_of_creation 
   FROM expense_table et 
   WHERE et.piece_unit_parent_id = put.piece_unit_id
   ) = :dateOfExpenseCreation 
AND project_id = :projectId
```

At first I thought I got a jackpot with that one because it gave me responses on  the first try (I usually spend a whole day just thinking about the structure of the query, I hate them), I never gave it too much thought, but the days passed by and it stopped giving me responses, so I'm guessing that maybe, the query was comparing some other dates inside the WHERE clause, more precisely, the dates on which the pieces where created.
Now that I reread it again it looks like a pretty bad query...

The way in which I'm storing dates (from the children side):

```
public void insertExpense(Expense expense) {

    long now = Converters.dateToTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    expense .setDate_of_creation(now);
    long edited = System.currentTimeMillis();
    expense .setLast_edited(edited);

    Log.println(Log.WARN, TAG, "insertExpense: date of creation is: " + expense.getDate_of_creation());
    Log.println(Log.WARN, TAG, "insertExpense: expense project is: " + expense.getParent_project_id());
    Log.println(Log.WARN, TAG, "insertExpense: expense piece parent is: " + expense.getPiece_unit_parent_id());


    insert(expense);
}
```

The observer side:

```
Log.println(Log.ERROR, TAG, "getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: specific date is: " + specificDate);
Log.d(TAG, "getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: project id is: " + project);

    MyObserver
            .observeOnce(
                    pieceUnitRepository.getPieceUnitsWhereDateOfExpenseCreation(
                            specificDate,
                            project
                    ),
                    pieceUnits ->
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: piece units are: " + pieceUnits);
                                if (pieceUnits != null && pieceUnits.size() > 0) {
                                    PieceUnit p = pieceUnits.get(0);

                                    Log.println(Log.WARN, TAG, "getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: Hello there ;) : " + p.getBeginning_date());
                                }
```

The Logd's:

```
insertExpense: date of creation is: 18469
insertExpense: expense project is: 1
insertExpense: expense piece parent is: 4
getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: specific date is: 18469
getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: project id is: 1
getPieceUnitGroupedByExpenseProductsAtDateAndProject: piece units are: []
```

I'm not asking for a full solution, but any input could point me in the right direction, so thanks in advance.

Comment: You provide SQL and Java code in your question which make it unclear of what the problem is. If the issue is with the query then you will have to provide also sample data of both tables and expected results in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

**Final answer** (from second update):

```
        SELECT 
           put.* 
        FROM piece_unit_table put 
        WHERE
           EXISTS(
           SELECT
               1
           FROM
               expense_table et
           WHERE
               et.date_of_creation = :dateOfExpenseCreation AND et.piece_unit_parent_id = piece_unit_id
               ) AND
           put.project_id = :projectId
```

***EDITS***

**First answer :**

In SQL there seems to be a function that helps on these cases:

`all` or `not exist`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439405/11214643

In the SQLite case there doesn't seem to be a direct equivalence, and every solution seems to be a case by case workaround depending on the type of clause.

In my case I `LEFT JOIN`-ed the children table, but `group by`-ing it before the join to avoid repeated rows on the left table.

As is expected, it was during the child table sub-query, that I filtered the table by their  date condition

```
        SELECT put.* 
        FROM piece_unit_table put 
        LEFT JOIN(
           SELECT
               piece_unit_parent_id
           FROM
               expense_table et
           WHERE
               et.date_of_creation = :dateOfExpenseCreation
           GROUP BY
               et.piece_unit_parent_id
               ) et1 
        ON
           et1.piece_unit_parent_id = put.piece_unit_id 
        WHERE
           put.project_id = :projectId
```

UPDATE:

It seems that behind curtains(either be SQLite or the ROOM interface), the LEFT JOIN is happening before the sub-query executes its own WHERE clause, as a result, the query is giving me parents, even when there are no children that meet the criteria, so the solution was to bring an additional column from the child temp table to the 'front', and check for it's non null-ability.

```
        SELECT 
           put.*,
           et1.puId AS expPuId 
        FROM piece_unit_table put 
        LEFT JOIN(
           SELECT
               piece_unit_parent_id AS puId
           FROM
               expense_table et
           WHERE
               et.date_of_creation = :dateOfExpenseCreation
           GROUP BY
               et.piece_unit_parent_id
               ) et1 
        ON
           et1.puId = put.piece_unit_id 
        WHERE
           put.project_id = :projectId AND expPuId NOT NULL
```

UPDATE 2:

Thanks to @forpas

The EXISTS and NOT EXISTS operators are in fact supported by SQLite, also, what was bringing me parents even when no children met the criteria was the second WHERE clause that was applied directly to the left table, but even if there was no clause applied to this table, it would've still gave me answers, because that's how LEFT JOIN works, if there are no matches it fills them with NULL's.

Here is a query that has the expected result, but does it better.

```
        SELECT 
           put.* 
        FROM piece_unit_table put 
        WHERE
           EXISTS(
           SELECT
               1
           FROM
               expense_table et
           WHERE
               et.date_of_creation = :dateOfExpenseCreation AND et.piece_unit_parent_id = piece_unit_id
               ) AND
           put.project_id = :projectId
```

Comment: SQLite does not support ALL, but it does support EXISTS and NOT EXISTS. Also there is no case that *the LEFT JOIN is happening before the sub-query executes its own WHERE clause*.

Comment: thanks @forpas.
You are completely right, the WHERE clause on my first answer was indeed filtering it (and the important part here is that by *it*, I mean the sub-query table), the problem was the second clause was picking all parent rows that complied with its own clause which was the project id.
Also the EXISTS and NOT EXISTS are indeed supported, my problem may have been a syntax error, I was tired yesterday and it was very late.
I'll update the answer.